# Iterating through JSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on a bookmarks project, and right now I'm trying to figure out how to deal with JSONs. 
Say I retrieve a JSON of this form, with some user's lan, and the information about their bookmarks:

```
{   "lan_id": "888888",
    "bookmarks": [{
            "id": "1",
            "bm_name": "Google News",
            "bm_link": "news.google.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "bm_name": "CNBC",
            "bm_link": "cnbc.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "bm_name": "MSN",
            "bm_link": "msn.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go through this structure and extract the information I need? Right now I just want to be able to console.log each batch of links like this:

```
1
Google News
news.google.com

2
CNBC
cnbc.com

...
```

After grabbing the JSON, I'm trying to use jquery's $.each function to iterate through this, but I'm getting confused. It feels like I should be nesting two $.each functions, but I'm not getting the correct output.

Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array in bookmarks, something like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "lan_id": "888888",
  "bookmarks": [{
      "id": "1",
      "bm_name": "Google News",
      "bm_link": "news.google.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "bm_name": "CNBC",
      "bm_link": "cnbc.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "bm_name": "MSN",
      "bm_link": "msn.com"
    }
  ]
};
obj.bookmarks.forEach(function(bmark, index){
   console.log(index+1);
   console.log(bmark.bm_name);
   console.log(bmark.bm_link);
});
```

Comment: Given the fact that you're not manipulating the data why use `Array#map` and not just `Array#forEach`?

Comment: @Pineda you are right, .map() creates a new array and .each would be better here. thanks for pointing, i have changed the code.